# SAPUI5 XML View Table Color

Tags: sapui5

I´ve started with my first SAPUI5 application and build a responsive table.
Now I have the requirement to color specific rows depends on a value in the model.

I´m using a XML-View.

Could I define a method in my controller for that? (How it should be working?)

Home.view.xml

```xml
<Table id="idMachineTable"
    inset="false"
    items="{
        path: 'machinemodel>/collection'
    }">
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Title text="Header" level="H2"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <columns>
        <Column
            width="12em">
            <Text text="Product" />
        </Column>
        <Column
            hAlign="Right">
            <Text text="Price" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier
                    title="{machinemodel>test}"
                    text="{machinemodel>test}"/>
                <Text
                    text="{machinemodel>test}" />   
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Comment: Have you tried the following command? `google sap.m.Table row color`

Comment: Sure, but I don´t find a satisfactory answer for a xml view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the answer @schnoebel provided

here is an alternate way ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kusuyitagu/edit?html,output)), in the Items binding define a change handler

```
items="{
    path: 'machinemodel>/collection',
    events: {
      change: '.onItemsChange'
    }
}"
```

then in the handler add your style class

```js
onItemsChange: function(oEvent){
   var oTable = this.byId("idMachineTable");

   oTable.getItems().forEach(function(oItem){
      var oContext = oItem.getBindingContext("machinemodel");
      if (oContext && oContext.getObject().status === 'A'){
         oItem.addStyleClass("overdue");
      } 
  });   
}
```

Comment: I like your solution too. I have learned that the binding has a change event that i can subscribe to! But beware, that this solution does not change the color of the row if there are changes in the items of the /collection. Added an example to your [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/venifidabi/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with a [customdata attribute that creates a dom attribute](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/1e/f9fefa2a574735957dcf52502ab8d0/content.htm). Then you can select the rows you want to color via css.

```xml
<ColumnListItem>
   <customData>
      <core:CustomData key="mydata" value="{machinemodel>status}" writeToDom="true" />
   </customData>
   <cells>
     ...
```

```css
<html:style type="text/css">
   tr[data-mydata="B"] {
     background-color: #faa !important;
   } 
</html:style>
```

Full example on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/yobubebese/1/edit?html,js,output).